# How to setup angularjs 1.5.x work with systemjs and typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular

I want to keep all my code still in 1.x and also want code is easy to upgrade to angularjs 2 latter. To make my code follow angular 2 style, I want to work with typescript and systemjs in 1.5.x firstly.

Does anyone have a work-around/code on how to setup angularjs 1.5.x work with systemjs and typescript?

This is the best match I found use babel as compiler: https://github.com/swimlane/angular1-systemjs-seed
**But I want systemjs works together with typescript in angular 1.**

Comment: This should get you started. http://legacytotheedge.blogspot.com.au/2015/01/using-es6-with-your-angularjs-project.html

Answer (score 1):

There are some seed projects to get you started with angular and jspm (es6):

https://github.com/angularclass/NG6-starter/tree/jspm
https://github.com/davinkevin/angularjs-jspm-seed

This one is for jspm + typescript 
https://github.com/b091/ts-skeleton/

Comment: it's not match with what I want: angular1 + typescript + systemjs

Comment: jspm is just a wrapper around systemjs (same dev group) abd uses systemjs so jspm + typescript + angular 1.x is pretty close to your needs